# How to add column with alternate values in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following sample dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('start','end'), ('start1','end1')] ,["start", "end"])
```

and I want to explode the values in each row and associate alternating 1-0 values in the generated rows. This way I can identify the start/end entries in each row.

I am able to achieve the desired result this way

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
df = (df.withColumn('start_end', fn.array('start', 'end'))
        .withColumn('date', fn.explode('start_end'))
        .withColumn('row_num', fn.row_number().over(w)))
df = (df.withColumn('is_start', fn.when(fn.col('row_num')%2 == 0, 0).otherwise(1))
        .select('date', 'is_start'))
```

which gives

```
| date   | is_start |
|--------|----------|
| start  | 1        |
| end    | 0        |
| start1 | 1        |
| end1   | 0        |
```

but it seems overly complicated for such a simple task.

Is there any better/cleaner way without using UDFs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=streaming#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) along with [`pyspark.sql.functions.array`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=streaming#pyspark.sql.functions.array).

First create an array out of your `start` and `end` columns, then explode this with the position:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, posexplode

df.select(posexplode(array("end", "start")).alias("is_start", "date")).show()
#+--------+------+
#|is_start|  date|
#+--------+------+
#|       0|   end|
#|       1| start|
#|       0|  end1|
#|       1|start1|
#+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `union`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('start','end'), ('start1','end1')] ,["start", "end"])
df = df.withColumn('startv', F.lit(1))
df = df.withColumn('endv', F.lit(0))
df = df.select(['start', 'startv']).union(df.select(['end', 'endv']))
df.show()
```

```
+------+------+
| start|startv|
+------+------+
| start|     1|
|start1|     1|
|   end|     0|
|  end1|     0|
+------+------+
```

You can rename the columns and re-order the rows starting here.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation in my use case. In my situation i had Huge dataset(~50GB) and doing any self join/heavy transformation was resulting in more memory and unstable execution .

I went one more level down of dataset and used flatmap of **rdd**. This will use map side transformation and it will be cost effective in terms of shuffle, cpu and memory.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('start','end'), ('start1','end1')] ,["start", "end"])
df.show()
+------+----+
| start| end|
+------+----+
| start| end|
|start1|end1|
+------+----+

final_df = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: [(row.start, 1), (row.end, 0)]).toDF(['date', 'is_start'])
final_df.show()
+------+--------+
|  date|is_start|
+------+--------+
| start|       1|
|   end|       0|
|start1|       1|
|  end1|       0|
+------+--------+
```